# Render google map with full screen on initialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I have been working with Google maps for quite some time now but I am stuck at a point. I have a container div in which I am rendering my map but initially its `display` is `none`. I have a floating button and I want that on its click the container's `display` should change to `block` and it should trigger the fullscreen event so the map is displayed in full screen. So far I have done this:

```
// html for map

<div id="searchMap" class="search-map">
  <div class="embed-responsive">
    <div id="searchViewMap" style="height: 540px;"></div>
    <div id="restaurant-label" class="restaurant-info-container-search"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

initially div with `id="searchMap"` has `display: none`

```
// html for button to show the map

<img src="{{asset('/images/map_button.png')}}" class="content-section__map-button" onclick="showMobileMap()">
```

That is an image button.

```
// JavaScript method onclick of the button

function showMobileMap() {
  $('#searchMap').css('display', 'block');
  $('#searchViewMap div.gm-style button[title="Toggle fullscreen view"]').trigger('click');
}
```

Now the problem that I am facing is that when I click the button for the first time it displays the container with the map but it doesn't make it full screen. And when I click the button again it makes it full screen. I don't know why this is happening but I want that the map renders full screen on the first click.

Answer (score -1):

try to change :

```
<div id="searchViewMap" style="height: 540px;"></div>
```

to

```
<div id="searchViewMap" style="width: 100%; min-height: 100vh;"></div>
```

or add css :

```
#searchMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;    
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: The question says Full Screen, not Full Browser.